# control system : time domain analysis

Tags: transfer-function, control-systems, time-domain, electrical-signal

[image]

This is the question. According to this, when we solve for transfer function we will get $20/s^2+5s+24$. but this is not the correct format as numerator should be equal to the last term, i.e., 24, in this case, as it is natural frequency of oscillation.

So I multiplied the equation by 24 and divided it by 24. now I have $(20/24)x (24/s^2+5s+24)$. I can now find natural and damped frequency and zeta as well.

But what about the 20/24?  Let's suppose it as $K$. How to solve for all the time domain specifications and how to find $c(t)$, i.e., expression for the output response if subjected to unit step function.